# javascript execution order (with example in d3-force)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph
I'm trying to understand this code in order to figure out how d3-force works.

I trace the variable `nodes` to see how they assign position to them.

```
  // Replace the input nodes and links with mutable objects for the simulation.
  console.log(nodes); // Added by me
  nodes = d3.map(nodes, (_, i) => ({id: N[i]}));
  console.log(nodes); // Added by me
  links = d3.map(links, (_, i) => ({source: LS[i], target: LT[i]}));
```

Somehow the variable `nodes` after `d3.map` has all the variables needed for forceSimulation, including `index`, `x`, `y`, `vx`, `vy`.

I think this has more to do with how javascript execute the functions below it than d3 itself, but I don't know how.

I also printed `N` but there's nothing special about it. Just the `id` value, as expected from the previous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those properties you mentioned are created by the simulation itself, **after** you pass the nodes to the simulation.

As the [documentation states](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_nodes),

> Each node must be an object. The following properties are assigned by the simulation:
>
> - index - the node’s zero-based index into nodes
> - x - the node’s current x-position
> - y - the node’s current y-position
> - vx - the node’s current x-velocity
> - vy - the node’s current y-velocity

When you first log the nodes, they do not have those properties. However, after the simulation runs, those properties will show up on the object already logged on the console. In Chrome, for instance, you'll see a blue icon saying something like *"the object below was evaluated just now"*. If you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(nodes))`instead of `console.log(nodes)` you'll see the original object.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightment! So it turns out it's a property of browsers' dev tool that they evaluate the reference to the variable only when I clicked it. `console.log(JSON.stringify(nodes))` seems to be better when tracing variables, instead of just `console.log()`.